# Can I send Kinesis Video Stream Signaling channel to KVS Video Stream?

Tags: amazon-kinesis, amazon-kinesis-video-streams

Streaming by WebRTC using this tutorial
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesisvideostreams-webrtc-dg/latest/devguide/kvswebrtc-sdk-js.html
is quite simple.
I'm trying to establish whether it is possible to send the stream from the Kinesis Video Stream Signaling channel to KVS Video Stream?
I need the KVS Video stream because I need to implement face recognition with Amazon Rekognition.

Thank you